# Error AsyncTask al cambiar de Activity

Tags: java, android

Cuando registro un usuario en la app se ejecuta un AsyncTask que realiza el envío de un email hacia mi cuenta de gmail, esto funciona correctamente pero genera un error y hace que se cargue una vez la nueva Activity y después carga de nuevo la misma Activity.

Este es el error en el Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matia.tonum, PID: 9873
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{30bd839 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,242} not attached to window manager
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:386)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:312)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
                      at com.example.matia.tonum.SendMail.onPostExecute(SendMail.java:53)
                      at com.example.matia.tonum.SendMail.onPostExecute(SendMail.java:19)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

La linea 53 es el progressDialog.dismiss(); en el siguiente código

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Empresa registrada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

y la linea 19 es (public class SendMail extends AsyncTask)

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    //Declaring Variables
    private Context context;
    private Session session;

    //Information to send email
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

    //Progressdialog to show while sending email
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //Class Constructor
    public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Registrando ","Espera, por favor...",false,false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Empresa registrada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

        try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            mm.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            mm.setText(message);

            //Sending email
            Transport.send(mm);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Y así llamo al AsyncTask para enviar el email en mi Activity

```
private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String subject = "Empresa " + nombreusuario + ", " + Ciudad + ", " + País + ".";
        String message =    "Datos de la empresa " + nombreusuario
                            + '\n' +  '\n' +
                            "Nombre: " + nombreusuario + '\n' +
                            "Dirección: " + direccion + '\n' +
                            "País: " + País + '\n' +
                            "Ciudad: " + Ciudad + '\n' +
                            "Tipo de Empresa: " + TipodeEmpresa + '\n' +
                            "Rut o DNI: " + rutodni + '\n' +
                            "Correo electrónico: " + email + '\n' +
                            "Contraseña: " + password + '\n' +
                            "ID Usuario: " + user_id + '\n' + '\n' +
                            "Activo: " + activo;

        //Creating SendMail object
        //SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        SendMail sendem = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sendem.execute();
    }
```

Este AsyncTask lo llamo en la Activity donde registro a los usuarios y después de registrar al usuario hay un Intent que nos lleva a la nueva Activity.

Yo creo que el error es porque la app cambia de Activity antes de terminar de enviar el email o de terminar de ejecutar el AsyncTask, pero no sé cómo podría hacer que primero termine de ejecutarse y luego cambie de Activity...

Espero entiendan y puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `doInBackground()` ejecuta tareas en segundo plano y no tiene que ver con el manejo de la UI del usuario, en `onPreExecute()` , en `onPostExecute()` y en `onProgressUpdate()` si se actualaiza la UI , ahora, cuando vos en `onPostExecute()` cerras el dialogo puede ser que otra activity venga al foreground(cambiando las vistas) y te salte el problema de windows leak por que no cerras el dialogo cuando inflas otras vistas

Acordando al ciclo de vida de una Activity, antes de mostrar otra vista siempre pasa primero por el `onPause` y despues el `onStop`, en tu onPause pone lo siguiente

```
 @Override
    public void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
        if(progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

y en tu `onPostExecute()` tambien

```
if(progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
```